# How to link Outlook scheduling assistant with Dynamics 365?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

There is a way to create an appointment in Dynamics CRM via activities, this opens up a form for the data. After creating this appointment, it shows up in outlook, which is nice, but I would like to see a scheduling assistant to help create the appointment before saving it. As of now I don't see any way to see conflicts before creating the appointment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the Outlook integration (either using classic client or App for Outlook), then Outlook is the best place to create the appointment (with scheduling assistant), after that simply "Track" it to CRM by `Set Regarding` or `Track without regarding`. [Read more](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/posts/dynamics-365-app-for-outlook-part-1-the-basics)

CRM activity UI will be very limited, you will see conflicts on save only that too its not very intuitive.